# How to use an array of pointers already filled as parameter of a function/method

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers

I'm doing an Oriented Object Snakes & Ladders version. So I have a class called Game which have a method called startGame() and a method called play(). Here's the header of the class.

```
#ifndef GAME_H_INCLUDED
#define GAME_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include "Tiles.cpp"
class Game{
 private:
    int tiles, snakes, ladders, penalty, reward, players, turns, currentTurn;
    char mode;
 public:
    Game();
    Game(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, char);
    void play(Tiles*, unsigned int);
    void startGame();
};
#endif
```

So first I create an array of pointers of and added class named Tiles (which has 2 inherited classes: Snakes and Ladders) and I fill it with objects of those inherited classes.

```
void Game::startGame(){
 int tiles, n1, n2, n3;
 Tiles * board[tiles];

 for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    board[i] = new Normal(i+1);
 }

 for (int i2=0;i2<n2;i2++){

    do {
    nTileS = rand() % tiles;
    }while (board [nTileS] -> getType() != 'N');
    board[nTileS] = new Snake(nTileS+1);
 }

 for (int i3=0;i3<n3;i3++){
    do {
        nTileL = rand() % tiles;
    }while (board [nTileL] -> getType() != 'N');
        board[nTileL] = new Ladder(nTileL+1);
 }
```

Once I created the array, I call a function called play(), which has all the logic about the game but I want the array I created as a parameter. `play(board[tiles], tiles);`

```
void Game::play(Tiles* board, unsigned int nBoard){
 cout<< "test" << endl;
 for (int i=0; i<nBoard; i++){
    board[i].showTile();//method that prints the info of the object, just for testing
 }
```

But as a result, the code gives me only `test`, so actually the method works but apparently it doesn't recognize the objects of my array of pointers. I just want to know how to use that array of pointers in this case. Thank you by the way

Comment: Probably unrelated: Try to avoid naked `new`. I can't see any `delete`. This can cause memory leaks and other serious problems. Use STL containers or smart pointers. This `Tiles * board[tiles];` looks like a variable-length array. It's not part of standard C++. You are using a compiler extension and you should try to avoid it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Did you check if `showTile` is called correctly?

Comment: `tiles` in `startGame` is an uninitialised local variable as are `n1`, `n2` and `n3`